# Solidity のコンストラクタはどのような役割を持っていますか？

Tags: solidity

test_1 と test_2 の違いがわかりません。（testMessageを呼び出すような関数を作成すると、両方とも同じように機能します）

```
contract test_1 {
  string testMessage = "Hello,world!";
}

contract test_2 {
  string testMessage;
    constructor() {
      testMessage = "Hello,world!";
    }
}
```

先述した通り、testMessageを呼び出してみるとどちらも Hello, world がちゃんと表示されます。

```
function getMessage() public view returns(string){
  return testMessage;
}
```

**実行結果:**

```
Hello,world!
```

コンストラクタが特別な意味を持っていることは知っていますが、それが具体的にどんな役割を持っているのかが分かりません。

Answer (score 0):

以下のドキュメントにあるように、一度だけ実行されるものになります。

https://solidity-jp.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/contracts.html

> コントラクトが作られた時、constructor ( constructor キーワードで宣言されるファンクション)が一度だけ実行されます。